# How to compress lots of similar files?

Tags: java, zip, compression

In java I have a `List<byte[]>` consisting of 30_000 items (each ~1.2kB in size). I want to save that data to disk. Those byte-arrays are all similar (each representing utf-8-encoded json-Data), but are not identical.

Currently, I am using a `ZipOutputStream` to write each byte-array as one file into one big zip-File.

```
import java.util.zip.*;

var fileCount = 0;
try (var out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.zip"))) {
    for (var byteArray : listOfbyteArrays) {
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry((fileCount++)+".json")));
        out.write(byteArray);
    }
}
```

This solution, however, creates a poorly compressed zip-file. Each file is compressed with a factor of approximatly 50%. However the similarity of files is not used:

```
out.zip compression 45%
  1.json compression 45%
  2.json compression 46%
  3.json compression 44%
  4.json compression 45%
  ...
```

If I compress the result in my windows explorer (creating a zip inside a zip), the compression is MUCH higher afterwards (approximalty factor 99%):

```
zipInZip.zip compression 99%
  out.zip compression 45%
    1.json compression 45%
    2.json compression 46%
    3.json compression 44%
    4.json compression 45%
    ...
```

How can I create a zip file in java, that uses the similarity of files to archive high compression?

Answer (score 2):

A ZIP file is not really suitable for this.  There are two reasons:

- Short files don't compress well, and ZIP is compressing each file in the archive individually.
- The DEFLATE compression algorithm by ZIP is rather dated.

You will get much better compression if the files in the archive are compressed *together* rather than individually ... as ZIP does.

So, create a TAR archive of the uncompressed JSON files, then compress the entire file using GZIP compression.  You would need to use a 3rd-party TAR I/O library.

---

Other option would be to use the standard `ZipOutputStream` to create a ZIP file with no compression (set the compression level to 0) and then GZIP it.

Zipping a ZIP that was created without compression would work ... but it is (IMO) clunky.

The standard `ZipOutputStream` only supports DEFLATE, but there are 3rd-party Java ZIP file I/O implementations that support other compression algorithms.  But simply getting ZIP to use a newer algorithm won't address the small file effect.

Comment: Better would be to use zstd or xz, which have much longer look-back than deflate. The deflate look back is limited to 32K, which is right at the limit for those 30K files.

Comment: I updated the question to be less ambiguous :) My List contains 30,000 files...

Comment: Ah. Then deflate can do a good job with redundancy across concatenated 1.2K files.

Comment: Yea ... that was the small file effect I was alluding to.  Perhaps I should spell it out.

Answer (score 0):

Compression of many similar files is a known limitation of zip files. Use the "zip-in-a-zip"-method for high compression. Even though it might be bulky to for the consumer to have to unzip twice.

```
try (var compressed = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("zipInZip.zip"))) {
    compressed.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("out.zip"));
    try (var uncompressedContainer = new ZipOutputStream(compressed)) {
        uncompressedContainer.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
        for (var byteArray: listOfbyteArrays) {
            uncompressedContainer.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry((fileCount++)+".json")));
            uncompressedContainer.write(byteArray);
        }
    }
}
```